# UISwitch in table view were not able to disabled by a custom switch

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I intended to use a custom Switch to control all the switches that programmatically designed in the tableview. I tried to use the control events of custom Switch to control all the switches, but it still couldn't work. I've declared the UISwitch for tableview in the VC's implementation.

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    UISwitch *switchObj;
    NSArray *infoDetail;
}
@synthesize customSwitch;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    infoDetail = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Main door",@"Main door 2",@"Main windows",nil];
    [customSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(stateChanged:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [infoDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
switchObj = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 1.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
switchObj.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
[switchObj addTarget:self action:@selector(alarmOn:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
cell.accessoryView = switchObj;
return cell;
}
- (void)stateChanged:(UISwitch *)switchState{
    if (customSwitch.isOn) {
     switchObj.enabled = YES;
    }
    else{
    switchObj.enabled = NO;
    }
}
- (void)alarmOn:(id)sender{
if ([sender isOn]) {
    NSLog(@"Switch toggled on");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Switch toggled off");
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the problem you faced. Also you only have added the switch and you haven't provided any kind of tag or something to handle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bringing your switchObj declaration code inside **UITableView's** `cellForRowAtIndex` method and delete from top.

```
UISwitch *switchObj;
```

Now the method will be like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [infoDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    UISwitch *switchObj = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 1.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    switchObj.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    [switchObj addTarget:self action:@selector(alarmOn:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged | UIControlEventTouchDragInside)];
    cell.accessoryView = switchObj;

    if (customSwitch.isOn) {
        switchObj.enabled = YES;
    }
    else{
        switchObj.enabled = NO;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Also when you change the state custom switch, reload the tableView too.
Change your `stateChanged` method as follows:

```
-(void)stateChanged:(UISwitch *)switchState{
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```